# Minimum value that not zero

Tags: applescript, integer-arithmetic

In Applescript, I need to find the integer value nearest to zero but not zero. Numbers are all zero or greater than zero. At present, I have three integers.

I guess I could write a loop, but is there an easier way?

examples:

```
{0,3,4} find 3. 
{1,0,0} find 1
{4,10,2} find 2
{0,0,0} find nothing or 0
```

Comment: Will the numbers in the list always be in numerical order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a loop because, at some point, every item in the list needs to be evaluated, so there's no getting around that (assuming an iterative method; you could, of course, write a recursive algorithm that doesn't contain an explicit loop—I'll illustrate both below).

### 1. Iteration

The iterative method keeps track of the lowest, non-zero number encountered as we work our way, one-by-one, through each number in the list.  When we reach the end of the list, the tracked value will be the result we're after:

```
on minimumPositiveNumber from L
    local L

    if L = {} then return null

    set |ξ| to 0

    repeat with x in L
        set x to x's contents
        if (x < |ξ| and x ≠ 0) ¬
            or |ξ| = 0 then ¬
            set |ξ| to x
    end repeat

    |ξ|
end minimumPositiveNumber

get the minimumPositiveNumber from {10, 2, 0, 2, 4} --> 2
```

### 2. Recursion

The recursive method compares the first item in the list with the lowest, non-zero value in the rest of the list, keeping the lowest, non-zero value:

```
on minimumPositiveNumber from L
    local L

    if L = {} then return 0

    set x to the first item of L
    set y to minimumPositiveNumber from the rest of L

    if (y < x and y ≠ 0) or x = 0 then return y

    x
end minimumPositiveNumber

get the minimumPositiveNumber from {10, 2, 0, 2, 4} --> 2
```